# How can I use the liveLiterals plugin option?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-jetpack-compose

How can I use the liveLiterals plugin option? When I try to apply it, I get this error: Multiple values are not allowed for plugin option androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin:liveLiterals.

```
freeCompilerArgs += [
        "-P",
        "plugin:androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin:liveLiterals=false"
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I solved this.
Just change `liveLiterals` to `liveLiteralsEnabled`.

```kotlin
freeCompilerArgs = freeCompilerArgs + listOf(
    "-P",
    "plugin:androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin:liveLiteralsEnabled=false",
)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio, go into File > Settings > Editor > Live Edit and select Live Edit of Literals. You don't have to add the plugin yourself as far as I know. It is built-in.

Comment: right i know it. However, if turn off LiveLiteral via the IDE, only the function calls that update the LiveLiteral are disabled and the LiveLiteral file is still created by the compiler. I'm going to try the only way to disable LiveLiteral file creation altogether.

Answer (score 0):

```
freeCompilerArgs = freeCompilerArgs + listof(
    "-P",enabled=false
    "plugin:androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin:liveLiteralsEnabled=false",
)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer). In particular, you should explain how your code improves on the very similar code in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74580392/10871073).